# How to convert radiobuttonlist in asp.net to mvc

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an asp.net web form application that I am trying to re-write in MVC. I'm stuck on how to handle bool? values. I'll show one example.

Demo.aspx:

```
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="FLOW_TARGET" 
  RepeatDirection="Horizontal" SelectedValue=""
   OnSelectedIndexChanged="FLOW_TARGET_SelectedIndexChanged"
    AutoPostBack="true">
   <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0" />
  <asp:ListItem Value="1" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

How can I convert this RadioButtonList asp.net into mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ASP.NET Html Helpers, there are three various methods you can use for each of the different helpers supplied for radio buttons.

1 - in the case if you have a model:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.x, "textHere", new { @checked = true })
```

then you can add attributes after checked=true to handle all bool values

2 - if you want to make a simple Radio :

```
@Html.RadioButton("nameHere", "valueHere", new { id = "yourId" })
```

3- to make a list of Radios:

You can start by using the foreach like this:

```
foreach (var x in Model.y)
{
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.something, x.Id) @x.Name
}
```

so you can always ovverid the RadioButtonFor or RadioButton with all you attributes and their values using this way,

i hope my answer is the right one for your case